# Add custom header based on file type

Tags: iis, web-config, http-headers, iis-7.5

We are trying to add a custom header (X-Robots-Tag) for sitemap files in IIS 7.5. However, it does not appear that IIS supports custom headers based on a file type or wildcard (only subfolders).

Can we add a custom header for only *.xml.gz files via Web.config?

We would like to avoid making the customization via code or on our load balancer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the [IIS UrlRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) and add a custom outbound rule to configure the custom header. Here is a sample rule you may want to use:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Set custom HTTP response header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.xml\.gz$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="The value you need for this header"/>
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

More info: [UrlRewrite documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#setting-response-headers)

Comment: Is there a way to make the value dynamic like today's date plus 7 days, if so, post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825497/iis-7-5-how-do-you-add-a-dynamic-http-expires-header

Comment: I use `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: So, if you want to change the `Cache-Control` header, what should you use? Is there a list of server variables somewhere that contains `RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag`? How does IIS know that `RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag` relates to the `X-Robots-Tag` header?

Comment: Hm... I see that `RESPONSE_Cache_Control` is working in order to set `Cache-Control`! Interesting...