# IIS 7.5 Adding Custom HTTP Response Headers for Only Specific File Types

Tags: http-headers, iis-7.5

In IIS 7.5, you can add custom http headers, but when you do, they are applied for all file types. I want the ability to use a custom http header only when serving specific file types (png,jpg,gif), without that same custom http header also being applied to all other file types requested from the web server.

I need a solution that achieves this via the web.config file, unless there is a coding solution that plays nice with a php 5.4 web application.

Comment: Definitely custom header and not mime type?

Comment: Yeah, custom headers ( as you would view using http://web-sniffer.net/ )

Comment: May this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type