# Add custom http response headers for files matching conditions

Tags: iis, http-headers, web-config

I need to add a custom http header to every http response from my IIS 8.5, but only for specific file types (css, js and html).

I've tried this solution 
[Add custom header based on file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type), but it seems outdated, and I'm getting errors for bad `web.config` file.

How it can be done on IIS 8.5?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution on this link still working [Add custom header based on file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type) for your problem.

You weren't able to use it because you need to install URL Rewrite module for IIS.

Please go to https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite , download, install it and then restart IIS. After this steps error about bad web.config file should gone