# Disallowing unneeded HTTP headers for non-HTML resources

Tags: iis, http-headers, web-config, mime-types, content-security-policy

The [Sonar](https://sonarwhal.com) test suite [makes the interesting point](https://sonarwhal.com/docs/user-guide/rules/no-html-only-headers/) that it should be considered bad practice to send the HTTP headers

- Content-Security-Policy
- X-Content-Security-Policy
- X-Frame-Options
- X-UA-Compatible
- X-WebKit-CSP
- X-XSS-Protection

when sending non-HTML resources.

I currently configure my IIS server using `web.config`, namely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' ; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/" />
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
                <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
                <add name="X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies" value="none" />
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
                <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But that configuration sends those headers no matter the type of the resource send. 
**How to make IIS selectively add those headers to the right types of files?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IIS UrlRewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (an IIS extension) and add a custom headers only for html resources.
Check this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type).

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: Thanks, but the linked question is about *adding* header based on the file type. I want to *remove* headers (I know I could achieve what I want by adding the header to all the `html` resources, and not to the others, but I'd rather proceed the other way around, and I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to achieve this).

Comment: @Nick: Sorry, next time I'll more specific. Clément: I tried to answer at your last question "How to make IIS selectively add those headers to the right types of files?"