# IIS Removing nosniff header for images

Tags: iis

I have an API that return me images, like:

/api/products/images/233 -> This will return me an 233.jpg image

But my IIS has a rule to add the X-Content-Type-Options header to the requests for security, but that break the images on Internet Explorer, so I need a way to remove this rule when the endpoint /products/images/ is called or a way to add the header only if it's no that endpoint.

I tried to use this about [Custom Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type)

But it didn't work, I tried like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove nosniff">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Content_Type_Options" pattern="/products/images/" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="none"/>
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

But it didn't change anything, the images still having the "nosniff" header.

Am I missing some configuration? Or there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match condition is checking if the header `RESPONSE_X_Content_Type_Options` contains the value `/products/images/` instead of `nosniff`. You can use a Location block to restrict this rule to `/products/images/`, then use `pattern="nosniff"` to find the value `nosniff`

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer/>
    ...
    <location path="products/images/">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <outboundRules>
                    <rule name="Remove nosniff">
                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Content_Type_Options" pattern="nosniff" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" value="none"/>
                    </rule>
                </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

See docs for  element: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Ps: I couldn't edit your answer since the "location path" doesn't allow slashs in the end/start of the string, so the fix is "path="products/images".