# iis web.config location path exclude files (= paths with extensions)

Tags: iis, web-config

I want to add customHeaders to all my routes. But only to actual paths in my domain and not files.

```
<location path="???">
```

Headers should be added to:

```
domain.com
domain.com/dashboard
```

but not to

```
domain.com/someimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use IIS rewrite module to write a custom outbound rule. It already has OOTB condition to check if a URL is a file.  Something like below, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type) question is similar:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Set custom HTTP response header">
      <match serverVariable="Custom header" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="Your value"/>
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```